# how to use num2str to represent a file name? struct from char error

Tags: matlab

i want to save data from text files to mat files. what is the error?

i tried to use num2str command but matlab says its an error:
 "The following error occurred converting from char to struct:
Conversion to struct from char is not possible."

```
for i=1:8
textFileName = [num2str(i) '.txt'];
t = readtable(textFileName);
matFileName = [num2str(i) '.mat'];
save(matFileName,'-ascii',t);
end
```

Comment: `save` is typically used to create binary files - it's very unusual to create a text file using it. The `-ascii` option only works for saving 2D numeric data to a text file, so it won't work with your `Table` object `t`. If you want to save the table then remove the `-ascii` option, and it will save to a binary file (noting that you need to use `'t'` as pointed out in one of the answers.)  For 2D numeric data consider using something like `csvwrite` instead.  Also, I wouldn't recommend creating a text file with a `.mat` extension because almost everyone expects `.mat` files to be binary.

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify your `save` call like this:

```
save(matFileName, 't', '-ascii');
```

Comment: It might worth pointing out that you need to pass the name of the variable to the `save` function, hence `save(filename, 't')` instead of `save(filename,t)`.